# Java - How can I append to a jTextArea from a socket?

Tags: java, sockets, append, jtextarea, serversocket

So, I decided to try to work on a ServerSocket/Socket instant messenger to get familiarized with how to use ServerSockets and Sockets. I am currently still working on the server side of the application, and am having trouble getting a jTextArea on the GUI to update with information sent from a client program.

Here is my code:

For the Socket side of things (ServerSocket class):

```
while (shouldRun) {
    inputMessage = (String)input.readObject();
    new jMessengerServerGUI().updateFeed(inputMessage);
    System.out.println(inputMessage);
}
```

And for the GUI (jMessengerServerGUI class):

```
public void updateFeed(String updateMessage) {
    txtServerFeed.append(updateMessage);
    System.out.println(updateMessage);
}
```

The methods are in separate classes, where the string inputMessage is received and sent flawlessly and is printed out in the console. The issue comes with updating the jTextArea txtServerFeed.

How can I best achieve writing to the TextArea when called from an outside class?

Comment: A [better example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504672/print-output-of-process-to-jtextarea-over-client-server-network-in-java/34510362#34510362), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178828/using-jframe-from-another-class/49185818#49185818), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155909/java-swing-gui-client-and-server-chat-app-textarea-not-updating/44158305#44158305)

Comment: *"Any feedback would be greatly appreciated"* - Isn't a question and is to broad. You will, hover, want to become familiar with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to make your Application Multi-threaded.
Where Server & Socket works separate thread rather than UI-Thread;

You can See that example:
https://github.com/khirulbasher/Multithreaded-Server-Client